# mem::transmute error when bounded to const N

Tags: rust

I do not understand why wouldn't the compiler let this example compile:

```rust
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};


fn foo<const N: usize>() -> [u32; N] {
    let mut res: [MaybeUninit<u32>; N] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

    for elem in &mut res[..] {
        unsafe { elem.as_mut_ptr().write(0) };
    }

    unsafe { mem::transmute::<[MaybeUninit<u32>; N], [u32; N]>(res) }
}
```

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> src/lib.rs:11:14
   |
11 |     unsafe { mem::transmute::<[MaybeUninit<u32>; N], [u32; N]>(res) }
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `[MaybeUninit<u32>; N]` (this type does not have a fixed size)
   = note: target type: `[u32; N]` (this type does not have a fixed size)

error: aborting due to previous error
```

It is clearly that N is the same for both result and input array. Is there anyway of achieving this?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a86fe0cce7ae1a32ea6c696328198519)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compiler limitation. They're indeed the same size, but the compiler is not able to see that (yet?).

You can use raw pointer casts to achieve this, because the compiler doesn't check the sizes are equal:

```rust
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

fn foo<const N: usize>() -> [u32; N] {
    let mut res: [MaybeUninit<u32>; N] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

    for elem in &mut res[..] {
        unsafe { elem.as_mut_ptr().write(0) };
    }

    unsafe { *(&res as *const [MaybeUninit<u32>; N] as *const [u32;N] ) }
}
```

Alternatively there's `array_assume_init`, still unstable so nightly-only though.

```rust
#![feature(maybe_uninit_array_assume_init)]

use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

fn foo<const N: usize>() -> [u32; N] {
    let mut res: [MaybeUninit<u32>; N] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

    for elem in &mut res[..] {
        unsafe { elem.as_mut_ptr().write(0) };
    }

    unsafe { MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(res) }
}
```

Comment: The pointer cast works on copy types, but It will not allowed to move the array otherwise. Maybe I can use the array_assume_init

Comment: `mem::transmute_copy` should also do the trick, as it doesn't check for equal sizes.